# <React/RCTDefines.h> file not found

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I am Using cocoapods to install react native and react. I just want to use a toast component(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-toast) which does ti have a cocoapods Installation. when i install and and run the app I am getting an error "" file not found error.
I have added header search path but still getting this error.
1)error
[image]

2)react-native-simple-toast xcode project Header search path
[image]

3) Main project Header search path
 [image]

Comment: When you do a pod install, do you see "React" as one of the pods installed? I suspect that the simple-toast lib has React as a dependency and that may be causing your issue

Comment: I think you either need to upgrade a bunch of things, or just add this pod in there and see if that works: `React/Core`

Answer (score 5):

Go to Project navigator > Libraries > RNFetchBlob.xcodeproj

Click on Build Settings and then the first item under "Targets"

Scroll down to 'Search Paths'

Double click to edit the 'Header Search Paths'

Add the following entry (click '+'): ${SRCROOT}/../../../ios/Pods/Headers.

Make sure to set it to recursive. (DOUBLE CLICK)

Clean (cmd + shift + K) and re-build (cmd + B)

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/461#issuecomment-553355501

Answer (score 4):

Try the following solution-

```
#if __has_include("RCTDefines.h")
  #import "RCTDefines.h"
#else
 #import <React/RCTDefines.h>
#endif
```

this works for me.

Comment: This solution is not ideal, you'll have to patch every imports that your library might use. The one from Rahul is better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have "RCTDefines" installed in your library list:

[image: C]

CLick the plus button at the bottom of the list to add it. Let me know if this helps you or if you need more info :)

Comment: Also worth running a build for your target after adding that lib to the list. And if you're developing for tvOS, make sure the lib you've selected is architectured for tvOS (often indicated by a `-tvos` suffix to the lib name) rather than the usual iOS.

Comment: Hi @ShaneG for me RCTDefines is not showing in the list while adding it in library dependencies. Help please.

Comment: @red-devil I haven't solved it. For that I have asked for help.

Comment: @amitpandya yeah you have to Add Other and dig it out...btw didn't work for me

Comment: @darkheartfelt are you talking about RCTDefines.h? And you added it to the library list, although it is not a library? Or did you create a headers phase in build phases?

Comment: @yossi this ended up being a much more severe issue where I had different versions of NPM and react was caching some older version everytime. I don't remember what I did but this wasn't the answer. If rctdefines is messed up like this it points to a larger issue of setup, not just a missing RCTDefines import or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for us (after fighting for days with this issue). FYI, the react-native version is *0.61.5*. In our case, the library failing was *'react-native-vector-icons'*. (Please tweak the steps *1* and *2* to suit the 3rd party library that fails for you)

The error message is:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
>   The following build commands failed:
>   CompileC ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m ./ios/build//Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNVectorIcons>.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>
> ### (1 failure)

The solution to the above error is:

**Step 1:** `rm -rf ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m` 
**Step 2:** `rm -rf ./ios/build/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o`
**Step 3:** `rm -rf ios/build`
**Step 4:** `rm -rf ios/Pods`
**Step 5:** `cd ios; pod install`
**Step 6:** Now, building the project will work fine using `react-native run-ios`

Although this isn't the permanent solution, it will unblock you if you're stuck.

Comment: Why do you remove RNVectorIconsManager.m file? isin't that necessary? Anyway, i have exactly same problem. When I add one library, it imports "RCTBridgeModule.h" and that imports React/RCTDefines.h that is not found. I am stuck...

Comment: @iiro: Good question. But AFAIK, even after the removal of  RNVectorIconsManager.m, nothing broke in my app related to the library. So went along with the fix. On a different note, was the above solution able to unblock you.

Comment: no, i don't have that library, but if I install this plugin https://github.com/Driversnote-Dev/react-native-kontaktio the xcode gives same error. Very Annoying! Either the library is not linked or when it is linked, the project cannot be built!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with sqlcipher.

It looked like the file was not capturing the library when I manually added it to my xcode configuration. From my understanding, this was happening since react-native was being linked through cocoapods, so the fix for my case was to manually link the pod in the pod file and run `pod install` instead of manually adding it to xcode.

In the context of cocoapods, I guess files are linked differently. But this is a guess, if someone can confirm I would really appreciate it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).